# Help interpreting OCSB test results

Tags: r, seasonality

Have a univariate time-series "qtrain" - which is quarterly stock "opening" values. Plotting the outputs of decompose() as well as stl() showed seasonality in the data.

Am trying to confirm seasonality with ocsb.test() after taking first-difference.

```
summary(ocsb.test(diff(qtrain, 1))$fitted.model)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + xreg)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-63.18 -38.12 -14.09  46.53 120.68 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
xregmf.x       NA         NA      NA       NA    
xregZ4    -0.5853     0.1736  -3.372  0.00226 ** 
xregZ5    -0.9206     0.1947  -4.729 6.32e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 56.9 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7708,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7539 
F-statistic: 45.41 on 2 and 27 DF,  p-value: 2.301e-09
```

Kindly help me interpret the above. 
**Am I correct in reading it as "Yes, there is seasonality, because of very small p-value: 2.301e-09" ?**

And I really do not understand what xregZ4 and xregZ5 are. Just that their coefficients are significant. Please could you tell me what they are?

Thank you!